# REST API Queries

Tags: rest-api, rest

I have written a custom REST service in Salesforce as below:

```
@RestResource(urlmapping='/MyRestWS/*')
global class CustomRestWS
{
    @HttpGet
    global static String getName()
    {
        return UserInfo.getUserName();
    }
    @HttpPost
    global static String sayHi(String test)
    {
        return 'Hi '+test;
    }
}
```

Please clarify my doubts below:

1. How to invoke it from outside, say from Postman or Java?  From Salesforce docs, it is mentioned that "You can set up authorization using OAuth 2.0 or by passing a Session ID." How to authorize using Session ID?
2. Is it mandatory to create a connected App in Salesforce if we want to invoke a Salesforce REST API? We cannot consume any salesforce REST API(even standard REST API) without creating a connected app?
3. Which authentication is most commonly used?
4. What is Basic Authentication, how to use Basic Authentication to invoke REST API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it as

```
baseUrlofyourorg+/services/apexrest/MyRestWS
```

If you want to use Oauth flow then I think you need the connected app. You can also expose your web service publically using Site guest user profile then you don't need any authentication or connected app.

```
grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82Hn
FVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&client_secret=
1955279925675241571&username=testuser%40salesforce.com&password=mypassword123456
```

this is how your request will look

A Basic curl example

for instance:

```
curl -d "grant_type=password&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&username=user@domain.com&password={Password}{SecurityToken}" "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
```

... will return

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/xxxxxxxxxxxxx","issued_at":"1347503304385","instance_url":"https://ap1.salesforce.com","signature":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","access_token":"XXXXtokenXXXXXX"
```

More detail can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm) or [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm)

The Most commonly used Authentication is [OAuth 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm) and its globally accepted on all major sites.

In [Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) we pass Username and password in request and I don't think SF support this authentication in accesing REST services.

There is a very good step by step example provided [here](http://www.oyecode.com/2014/08/start-building-your-own-rest-api-in.html)